# Remove ns2 as default namespace prefix

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a file that is printed with a default namespace. The elements are printed with a prefix of ns2, I need this to be removed, how it is with my code:

```
<ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="http://namespace" />
```

how I want it to be:

```
<foo xmlns="http://namespace" />
```

this is how I have coded it, something which as I see it should be enough for the ns2 to go away:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:bar="http://namespace" targetNamespace="http://namespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
...
```

the generated package-info turns out like this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://namespace", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.foo.bar;
```

I create the file like this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(generatedClassesPackage);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Foo>(new QName("http://namespace", "Foo"),
Foo.class, rootFoo), outputStream);
```

generatedClassesPackage is the package where package-info.java and the elements are.

The Foo object is defined and has elements like this::

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "group"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(name = "Group", required = true)
    protected List<Group> group;
```

Is it something I have missed? or have I misunderstood how this works?

Comment: If you give it a namespace and make it qualified then it needs to put the namespace somewhere to be valid as per the xsd.  You can remove the namespacing altogether, or change the prefix to be something more managable or change the top level element to have the xmlns of the main namespace so there are no prefixes for anything in that namespace.  So what you want is not valid xml per your xsds.  Do you want namespaced elements or not?

Comment: I think you confused me with not showing the attributes on that foo element.  Are you saying you want `<foo xmlns="http://namespace"/>` instead of `<ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="http://namespace" />`?

Comment: @DMoses yes, I should have included that, and yes, that is how I want it :).  I want this: 
    xmlns:ns2="http://namespace" 
in the root element.

Comment: ups, I mean without the ns2, so, xmlns="http://namespace"

Comment: @DMoses thanks for the catch with xmlns attribute, I have updated the op now.

Comment: Please post the Foo object, it thinks there is a sub-element that has a different namespace.

Comment: The Foo object is huge and has a different name actually, I masked it, but I have updated the op with how the object looks now.

Comment: You can check Group and all of it's members to make sure there are no extra namespaces laying around.  This happens because it thinks there are multiple namespaces to be marshalled and it doesn't know which one should be the targetnamespace vs a prefixed namespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely you have multiple namespaces in the response.  This will use the default convention of creating ns# namespace prefixes and one of them becomes the xmlns without a prefix.  If you want to control this you can do the following:

```
NamespacePrefixMapper mapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
        public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
            if ("http://namespace".equals(namespaceUri) && !requirePrefix)
                return "";
            return "ns";
        }
    };
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper);
    marshaller.mashal....
```

This will set the `http://namespace` as the default xmlns always and use ns# for all other namespaces when marshalling.  You can also give them more descriptive prefixes if you want.

Comment: this was sort of it! :) thanks a lot for the help. The issue was indeed multiple namespaces. I had one schema importing another, this was causing the problem. The code you posted here did not work directly, but I solved it by fixing the multiple schemas and then regenerating the code.

Comment: It should be noted that NamespacePrefixMapper is now an internal class in the JDK. So this solution does no longer count...

Comment: It was `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper` with latest Java 8's internal jaxb.

Answer (score 35):

All you need 2 do is when you open a new package select create package info 
in the package info add the following annotation or change it as needed

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = { @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", prefix = "") })
```

This will remove the ns2 prefix

Comment: Simple and very effective solution (worked perfectly for me).

Comment: How to generate package-info with this change using maven plugin?

Comment: Depends what maven plugin you use. If using `org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin`, you  activate the [JAXB2 Namespace Prefix Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Namespace-Prefix-Plugin) by adding `<arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>` into the `<args>` element in the plugin configuration. You also need to make sure the bindings.xjb has `<namespace:prefix name="my-prefix" />` elements added declaring what you want the prefix for each schema to be. The plugin link gives an example of the bindings.xjb. NOTE: this can generate for either `javax.xml...` or `jakarta.xml...` annotations

Answer (score 7):

Beginning from JDK6u18 the NamespacePrefixMapper technique is not used anymore.

Comment: `NamespacePrefixMapper` works perfectly with Java 11 and `jaxb-runtime` 2.3.2.

Answer (score 5):

I solve this deleting the file package-info.java into the jaxb classes package and re-compiling the application.

Comment: Yes! The generated `package-info.java` contains a `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema`, which seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want to generate

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

You need to create such package-info.java class in the same package with your JAXB pojo classes.

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"))
package com.amway.instantpayments.bankfileservice.jaxb.pojo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

And pay attention, if you will specify namespace as "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" and namespaceURI as "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" you will get

```
ns2:Document xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: The @XMLschema fixed the problem for me in Java 17. I also needed to remove schema check (remove `marshaller.setSchema(schema);`).
And my package-info.java was created by the  org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.15.2. So I needed to delete it to avoid conflict. I used the maven-clean-plugin to delete it during the phase process-sources.

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute value of elementFormDefault="unqualified" in

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:bar="http://namespace" targetNamespace="http://namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8:

I chagnge prefix name from '*ns2*' to '*fault*'.

**Firstly**, create your *DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper *.

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

    private static final String FAULT_PREFIX = "fault";

    private Map<String, String> namespaceMap = new HashMap<>();

    public DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper() {
        this.namespaceMap.put(NAMESPACE, FAULT_PREFIX);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        return namespaceMap.getOrDefault(namespaceUri, suggestion);
    }
}
```

**Secondy**, add your *DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper* to Marshaller property.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> void returnFault(T fault, SoapFault soapFault) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(fault.getClass());
        QName name = new QName(NAMESPACE, fault.getClass().getSimpleName());
        JAXBElement<T> element = new JAXBElement<>(name, (Class<T>) fault.getClass(), fault);

        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper());
        marshaller.marshal(element, soapFault.addFaultDetail().getResult());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        log.error("Exception when marshalling SOAP fault.", e);
    }
}
```

**Thirdly**, add following dependencies in gradle/maven.

```
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11'
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing some issues while creating the `QName`. For some reason, the `QName` does not take the custom `prefix` provided within the parameter. What is. `NAMESPACE` within the class `DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper`? I am trying your approach but it throws error for `NAMESPCE`.I have posted my question here. If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553941/creation-of-qname-takes-default-namesapce-prefix-rather-than-the-provided-parame

Answer (score 0):

Remove namespace from @XmlRootElement

Before: `XmlRootElement(name = "XXX", namespace = "abc.xsd")`

After: `@XmlRootElement(name = "XXX")`