# Remove ns2 prefix while JaxB marshalling an Element without @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, prefix

I have an object that I want to marshall but the schema does not have the @XmlRootElement annotation.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
public static class Foo
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "test1")
    public final static String TEST_1 = "Foo";

    @XmlElement(name = "Element1", required = true)
    protected String element1;

    @XmlElement(name = "Element2", required = true)
    protected String element2;
}
```

I marshalled the object by specifying a JaxBElement while marshalling

```
QName qName = new QName("", "Foo");
jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(qName, Foo.class, fooObj), new StreamResult(baos));
```

This results in the following XML after marshalling

```
<Foo xmlns:ns2="http://Foo/bar" test1="Foo">
    <ns2:Element1>000000013</ns2:Element1>
    <ns2:Element2>12345678900874357</ns2:Element2>
</Foo>
```

For my usecase I would like to marhsall this object without the ns2 prefix so that the XML would look like

```
<Foo xmlns="http://Foo/bar" test1="Foo">
    <Element1>000000013</Element1>
    <Element2>12345678900874357</Element2>
</Foo>
```

How can I marshall this object without the prefix?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095915/3454339) if you using Java 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are creating the `Foo` element in the wrong namespace. Looking at your desired output, you also want the `Foo` element to be in the `http://Foo/bar` namespace. To fix this problem, specify that namespace URI when you create the `QName`, instead of passing an empty string as the first argument:

```
// Wrong
QName qName = new QName("", "Foo");

// Right
QName qName = new QName("http://Foo/bar", "Foo");
```

To get rid of the generated `ns2` prefix for the namespace, you need to set the namespace prefix to an empty string. You probably have a `package-info.java` file with an `@XmlSchema` annotation. It should look like this:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://Foo/bar",
           elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
           xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://Foo/bar"))
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Note: Setting `prefix = ""` will cause JAXB to generate an `xmlns` attribute without a generated prefix name such as `ns2` in your XML.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get to the same solution but your explanation helped to understand why.