# JAXB How to remove default ns2 name space prefix in xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

While create request XML default "ns2" prefix added with name space declaration.

I am getting request XML as below format.

```
<ns2:ARTNCIS xmlns:ns2="http://namespace_uri">
    <ARTNCIS>
        <IDOCDATA>
            ...
        </IDOCDATA>
    </ARTNCIS>
</ns2:ARTNCIS>
```

Expected request XML should be like below,

```
<ARTNCIS xmlns="http://namespace_uri">
    <ARTNCIS>
        <IDOCDATA>
          ...
        </IDOCDATA>
    </ARTNCIS>
</ARTNCIS>
```

Below provided is package-info.java file.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://namespace_uri",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://namespace_uri")}
    )
package com.vam.abc.motor;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

While marshaling JAXB element added NamespacePrefixMapper to remove default "ns2" prefix. Find below code,

```
NamespacePrefixMapper mapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        if ("http://namespace_uri".equals(namespaceUri) && !requirePrefix)
            return "";
        return suggestion;
    }
};
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper);
marshaller.marshal(reqObject, document);
```

Below is my Root Element declaration.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "artncis" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "ARTNCIS")
public class ARTNCIS {
...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove ns2 as default namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589600/remove-ns2-as-default-namespace-prefix)

Comment: Nope. I have already added that part in my code. Not working for me.

Comment: Any news? Are you fixed?